# Find zero crossing points in a signal and plot them matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a signal 's' of voice of which you can see an extract here:

[image]

I would like to plot the zero crossing points in the same graph. I have tried with the following code:

```
zci = @(v) find(v(:).*circshift(v(:), [-1 0]) <= 0); % Returns Zero-Crossing Indices Of Argument Vector
zx = zci(s); 

figure
set(gcf,'color','w')
plot(t,s)
hold on
plot(t(zx),s(zx),'o')
```

But it does not interpole the points in which the sign change, so the result is:

[image]

However, I'd like that the highlighted points were as near as possible to zero.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks you for your responses in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
w = 1;
crossPts=[];
for k=1:(length(s)-1)
   if (s(k)*s(k+1)<0)
      crossPts(w) = (t(k)+t(k+1))/2;
      w = w + 1;
   end
end

figure
set(gcf,'color','w')
plot(t,s)
hold on
plot(t, s)

plot(crossPts, zeros(length(crossPts)), 'o')
```

Important questions: what is the highest frequency conponent of the signal you are measuring? Can you remeasure this signal? What is your sampling rate? What is this analysis for? (Schoolwork or scholarly research). You may have quite a bit of trouble measuring the zeros of this function with any significance or accurracy because it looks like your waveform has a frequency greater than half of your sampling rate (greater than your Nyquist frequency). Upsampling/interpolating your entire waveform will allow you to find the zeros much more precisely (but with no greater degree of accurracy) but this is a huge no-no in the scientific community. While my method may not look super pretty, it's the most accurate method that doesn't make unsafe assumptions. If you just want it to look pretty, I would recommend interp1 and using the 'Spline' method. You can interpolate the whole waveform and then use the above answer to find more accurate zeros.

Also, you could calculate the zeros on the interpolated waveform and then display it on the raw data.

A remotely possible solution to improve your data;

If you're measuring a human voice, why not try filtering at the range of human speech? This should be fine mathematically and could possibly improve your waveform.

Comment: I'd suggest not using a variable called `roots` as it's the name of a commonly used function.

Comment: But that only calculates the middle point of each pair of samples of the vector 't'. I could apply that algorithm to each pair of points in t(zx), but I'd like a more sophisticated method to interpol each pair than assuming the middle point is zero.

Comment: This code should search for sign changes and crossPts should be a vector of estimated roots/zeros. Have you tried it? I'm not sure how you would get more accurate than this with the data you have. Maybe you could try replacing my midpoint method with interp1? Check this source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: I updated my answer because the comment I was writing was too long. See above.